# SQL Server - Pull data from one row and update another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server with the following rows and columns (A-code, Desc, Length and B-code)

**A-Code  Desc     Length   B-Code**

A100     Rural-3D  25       A100

A100     NULL      55       B100

** In the first row A-code = B-Code

** In the second A-code<> B-Code and Desc is NULL

What I want to do is update the Desc column of the second row (A-code<> B-Code)  with the Desc value from the first row where the A-Code = B-Code

So that my final table result would be as follows

### **A-Code  Desc     Length   B-Code**

A100     Rural-3D  25       A100

A100     **Rural-3D**     55       B100

Please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[Desc] = b.[Desc]
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN MyTable B on a.[A-Code] = b.[A-Code] and b.[A-Code] = b.[B-Code]
WHERE a.[A-Code] <> a.[B-Code]
And a.[Desc] IS NULL;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d71e/1)